# redux-saga and firebase - Can't log the user out in a clean way

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

As a preface, let me mention that I have never used `redux-saga` or Firebase before today. I'm currently playing around to get a feel for both technologies.

I'm probably just missing a small concept, but I can't seem to get signout to work on my app. I figured that I should probably use `call()` to manage side effects within a saga, but nothing does the trick.

Here's the saga in question:

```
export function* deauthenticateUser() {
  yield takeLatest(DEAUTHENTICATE_REQUEST, function* () {
    try {
      yield call(firebase.auth().signOut)
      yield put({ type: DEAUTHENTICATE })
    }
    catch (error) {
      yield put({
        type: DEAUTHENTICATE_FAILURE,
        payload: error,
        error: true,
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I confirmed that calling `firebase.auth().signout()` directly works, it's only when using `call()` that I get the error action. Note that there's also no payload when the error gets dispatched.

[I checked in Firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut), and apparently `firebase.auth().signout()` returns a promise with nothing as it's content. I'm starting to wonder if that wouldn't be the problem, maybe `redux-saga` does not like having no result in it's promise when using `call()`?

How would one handle authentication and especially logging out with Firebase and `redux-saga`?

Comment: Can you try `yield call([firebase.auth(), firebase.auth().signOut])`?

Comment: It worked. Now... I'd be curious to know why. Shouldn't `yield call(firebase.auth().signOut)` be enough?

Comment: Tbh, I don't know. I've encountered this issue before and this solved it.

Comment: It's because of function context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't fully realize what `call()` did. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a comment from NULL SWEΔT, I had to call `yield call([firebase.auth(), firebase.auth().signOut])`.

The reason for this is because of JS' context and how `this` works. More details by reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [this](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/) (read documentation for `call([context, fn], ...args)`).